# "hostname given in the SMTP greeting MUST have an A record pointing back to the same server."

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, mx-record

I get this error when checking my DNS with an external tool:

> Spam recognition software and RFC821
>   4.3 (also RFC2821 4.3.1) state that the hostname given in the SMTP
>   greeting MUST have an A record
>   pointing back to the same server

It essentially states this path:

> mail.xxxx.com. -> mail.xxxx.com  ->
>   (IP of main server) -> xxxx.com

Now my postfix greeting appears as so:

> $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name

Is the problem because `$myhostname` is mail.xxxx.com and that is re-pointing to mail.xxx.com and THEN to my main server? I think I should change it to `$mydomain`

I would like to get some insight before I edit *yet another DNS entry* incorrectly.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message seems clear to me:

The DNS serving your zone **must** contain an A record (or AAAA if IPv6 but not a CNAME) equal to the hostname contained in the greeting message sent by your SMTP server. That's a requirement of RFC 2821.

In your case, if the hostname announced by your smtp server is "mail.exemple.com", then anybody **must** be able to resolve mail.exemple.com.

You can check your DNS records using dig. The result should be the following:

```
dig mail.exemple.com A +noall +answer       
;; global options:  printcmd
mail.exemple.com. 3600   IN      A       192.0.2.5
```

Your DNS zone and SMTP configuration must be set in adequation.

Comment: +1 It's also worth mentioning that it may take some time until your test tool updates their cached DNS records, if you have just added a new A record.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed my mail server problem with your answer and I was searching a lot on the web. Still wondering if this problem does not happens to others

Answer (score 1):

Well I answered my own question there, `$mydomain` (i.e. xxxx.com) should be used instead of `$myhostname` (mail.xxxx.com). I had seen this asked a lot but could not find any answered in search engines, so I guess I will leave this here. :)